# Populate an array of objects from an HTML input fields in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have a simpleform for a 'post' object (like a blog post), and one of the form fields is for the 'tags' collection. 'Tags' are a has_and_belongs_to_many association with only one field besides the rails defaults, 'name'.

I want to have the user type in their tags, and then match them to existing tags, and then save them into the 'tags' array in the controller using first_or_create before saving the post object.

I really don't know how to design this. What is the best approach?

'Post' form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @post, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :shared_url, :required => false, input_html: { class: 'span6' } %>
  <%= f.input :title, :required => false, input_html: { class: 'span6' }  %>
  <%= f.input :content, as: :text, :required => false, input_html: { class: 'span6' }  %>
  <%= f.input :tags, :required => false, input_html: { class: 'span6' } %>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Post", :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-large' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You can use Chosen-Select (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) and their multiple select, in order to select one of the existing tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should checkout this railscast [196-nested-model-form-revised](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised)